# How to update a single file in Heroku and not destroy app's data

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a Telegram bot hosted on Heroku with a PostgreSQL database and I want to edit a few Python files of my bot. Is it possible to update a single file and not destroy the app's data and everything? If so, then please give me step-by-step explanation as I'm new to Heroku.

Comment: Do you drop database and create a new one in your main python file?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't get it

Comment: I mean your postgresql data shouldn't be removed unless you are removing it somehow on the initial run

Comment: Okay, but how do I add a single file? I have a lot of files and uploading them will take time. I need to update 1 file only